# Setting Different Dates in Array.ForEach() Populates All Elements with Final Date

Tags: typescript, datetime, foreach

So, apparently I am trying to push a new object, containing date in object format, into an array. The dates need to be pushed in each object are already present in another array `date` in 'yyyy-mm-dd' string format.

To add them into an object to be pushed, I am taking each pre-determined date and creating a `new Date()` instance of it. This I then add to object in each loop. But unfortunately, it's ending up giving me last date in all objects in `arr` array.

Here is the code:

```
let dates: any[] = ['2018-01-22', '2018-01-28', '2018-01-30', '2018-02-11'];
let arr: any[] = [];

dates.forEach(el => {
  this.arr.push({
     date: new Date(el),
     ...
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 somfefunc() {
let dates: any[] = ['2018-01-22', '2018-01-28', '2018-01-30', '2018-02-11'];
let arr: any[] = [];

dates.forEach(el => {
  arr.push({
     date: new Date(el),
  });
}); 
console.log(arr);
 }  
}
```

i run this code snippet and i got this

```
0: Object { date: Date 2018-01-22T00:00:00.000Z }
1: Object { date: Date 2018-01-28T00:00:00.000Z }
2: Object { date: Date 2018-01-30T00:00:00.000Z }
3: Object { date: Date 2018-02-11T00:00:00.000Z }
length: 4
__proto__: Array []
```